# Finding the order of zero of $f+g$

Tags: complex-analysis

We have that $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ have zeros of order $m,n$ respectively at $z_0$, and we are asked to show that $f+g$ has a zero of order $k \geq min(m,n)$ at $z_0$.

So since $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ have zeros of order $m,n$ respectively at $z_0$ we can represent $f(z) = a_n(z-z_0)^n +...$ and $g(z) = b_m(z-z_0)^m+....$, and so $f+g = a_n(z-z_0)^n +b_m(z-z_0)^m+....$. Do we now consider cases where $m<n, n<m,$ and $n=m$. I tried this and its fine, if $m<n$ we get that $f+g$ has a zero of order m, for $n<m$ we get that $f+g$ has a zero of order $n$. Lastly for $n=m$ we get that $f+g$ has a zero of order $n=m$. From this do I conclude what is asked?

Comment: Mostly, but not quite. If $m = n$, then $f+g$ can have a zero of order $> n$.

Comment: ooh, okay why is that true?

Comment: What is the coefficient of $(z - z_0)^n$ in $f+g$?

Comment: Ohh, $a_n$, so $a_n$ has its own order? Is that what you're getting at?

Comment: $a_n$ is the coefficient in $f$. The coefficient in $g$ is $b_n$. Hence the coefficient in $f + g$ is?

Comment: $a_n +b_n$. Okay I see that, when I let $m=n$ on my work I left it as $b_m$ for $g$

Comment: And is $a_n + b_n$ guaranteed to be nonzero?

Comment: Well, not necessarily I don't think so, so it could have its own order, correct?

Comment: $a_n+b_n$ has its own order, so the entire term must have order $>n$, but from here are we able to just move to what we are asked to prove?

Comment: $a_n + b_n$ may or may not be $0$ if $a_n + b_n \neq 0$, then the order of the zero of $f+g$ at $z_0$ is $n$ (always in the situation $n = m$), if $a_n + b_n = 0$, then the order is larger than $n$, and can be arbitrarily large. For the extreme case consider $g = -f$, then the order of the zero is $\infty$.